# Django: how to query multiple fields in multiple tables

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have the following `SQL` statement that I know works:

```
SELECT year_table.year_value, races.race_name, results.category,results.position 
FROM races, year_table, results
WHERE year_table.year_value = variable AND year_table.year_id = results.year_id;
```

How would you convert this to `Django` query statements?

These are the models:

```
class YearTable(models.Model):
    year_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    year_value = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'year_table'

class Races(models.Model):
    race_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    race_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'races'

class Results(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey('YearTable')
    race = models.ForeignKey(Races)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'results'
```

Comment: Please show your models, rather than SQL.

Comment: You could `result = Results.objects.get(year_id=some_id)` (did not test this) then `result.year` and `result.race` (again did not test my snippets but something like that should work) If you need a more complete example please let me know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just get everything from results and use `select_related` to join the other models.

```
results = Results.objects.all().select_related('year', 'race')
```

Comment: Please note that selected_related `Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships...` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related